# How do I set compiler options -fobjc-arc in the VS 2017 IDE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do I set compiler options -fobjc-arc in the VS 2017 IDE?

This seems like it should be a simple thing just to set a couple of compiler options (a total of 10 characters) some place in the IDE. Yet, researching it yields convoluted discussions of CMAKE.  Is there an easier, less time consuming way to set a couple of compiler options?

Comment: In the project settings build tab?  That doesn't look like a C# compiler option though.  Is your question tagged with the wrong language?

Comment: Yes.  It is a Xamarin application.  I found the solution, these options may be specified through the "Additional mtouch arguments" field on the iOS Build tab.  Specifically, it needs to be -gcc_flags "-fobjc-arc"

Comment: You can write an answer to your own question, if you found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, these options may be specified through the "Additional mtouch arguments" field on the iOS Build tab. Specifically, it needs to be -gcc_flags "-fobjc-arc"

Please see here for further information:  [Enabling in ARC in xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724067/enabling-in-arc-in-xamarin)